# android: How to resume my app after a phone call was answered

Tags: android

I have a running app that prints a number each second. Now if i will press the HOME button this app will continue to work in the background and if i will return to it via long HOME press and press on the app, i will see that the prints occurred even during the time that the app was in background. So far so good.
Now I am making a phone call programmatically in my app during these number print outs.
the Call window opens , the number is being dialed and now i am trying to return BACK to my already active app and i CAN'T, all i can do is open a NEW activity which will be shown (this means all prints are erased).
So my question is: instead of using startActivity() which will open a new activity, How can i RETURN BACK to my activity in the background ?

This is my code so far:

to start the phone call, wait 1 sec and start a new runnable (which i hope will return me back):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_number.toString().trim()));
startActivity(intent);


Runnable showDialogRun = new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
}
};
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(showDialogRun, 1000);
```

now if i will remove the flag 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP' nothing will happened and when it will go to call window the app wont return at all.

Comment: Additionally keep in mind that even if you get the UI flow to return to your application, Android is under no obligation to keep your program running while something else is in the foreground - instead (if low on resources), it might have to kill your process, and then restart you in a new one.  So if you want this to be reliable, you should be figuring your time as a differential from one of the system timers and storing that differential in a place that would survive activity death and recreation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set new task flag

remove this line

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and set the android:launchMode="singleTop" in activity manifest . so when you start the activity , the existing activity instance will be brought to top.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: tried that already. with 'singleTop' nothing will happen, the phone call won't go back to the app, only when the phone call is finished.